# Getting SharePoint feature properties programatically using CSOM in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, features

I am working on "Getting properties of SharePoint Feature using CSOM in SharePoint Online".

Following is the code which I wrote :

```
  try
        {
            Password password = new Password();
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            securePassword = password.ConvertStringToSecureString();
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://mysite"))
            {

                Web web = context.Web;

                FeatureCollection featuresCollection = web.Features;

                context.Load(featuresCollection);

                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Feature feature in featuresCollection)
                {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Feature Definition ID:{0}", feature.DefinitionId);

                }
            }
        }
```

There is only one property `feature.DefinitionId` which I found for the feature object. Is there any way to get the other properties of feature?

PS- Can we do anything with `featureDefinitionID` and get the `Feature Definition XML` in Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 4):

CSOM Feature object exposes the following properties:

- [DefinitionId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.feature.definitionid(v=office.15).aspx) - *gets the GUID that identifies the Feature definition*
- [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.feature.displayname(v=office.15).aspx) - *feature name*

Such SSOM [Feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature(v=office.15).aspx) properties as [SPFeature.Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeature.definition(v=office.15).aspx) or [SPFeature.Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeature.properties(v=office.15).aspx) are not available in CSOM/REST.

Below examples demonstrate how to manage features using CSOM

Example: how to retrieve activated (web scope) features:

```
var webFeatures = ctx.Web.Features;
ctx.Load(webFeatures,fcol => fcol.Include(f => f.DisplayName,f => f.DefinitionId));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(var f in webFeatures)
{
   Console.WriteLine(f.DisplayName);
}
```

Example: how to activate a feature

```
 ActivateWebFeature(ctx.Web, new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb"),true); //active a Publishing feature
```

,where

```
public static void ActivateWebFeature(Web web, Guid featureId, bool force)
{
    var ctx = web.Context;
    web.Features.Add(featureId, force, FeatureDefinitionScope.None);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: @saikumar.tammisetty Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your issue

Comment: @grisha from my question it self i achived definitionid.but actually am expecting little more.i got an alternative using windows sharepoint services using soap call.am still awaiting for a better solution

Comment: DisplayName is not a Feature Property in CSOM either.

Comment: @BrianP That's just incorrect. I was able to load the DisplayName using the above example by Vadmin-Gremyachev . This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Which version of the CSOM DLL are you using? I tested in both 15.0.0.0 and 16.0.0.0

Comment: Can someone help me with the namespace to include for "Include". I am getting error "'FeatureCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'FeatureCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: The most current CSOM 2013-Version (15.0.5031.1001) does NOT have a DisplayName-Property for Feature