# Unable to get the DisplayName of feature using CSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, office-365, csom, features

I am trying to get the names of all the features available at site collection using CSOM. Below code works fine to get list of all the Features but i am unable to get the `DisplayName` property.

```
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(URL);
            Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(oWebsite, website => website.MasterUrl, website => website.CustomMasterUrl, website => website.Features);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Authenticated!");
            Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForeground;

            var webFeatures = clientContext.Web.Features;
            clientContext.Load(webFeatures, fcol => fcol.Include( f => f.DefinitionId));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var f in webFeatures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f.DefinitionId);
            }
```

Here is a [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129443/getting-sharepoint-feature-properties-programatically-using-csom-in-sharepoint-o) that explains how to get the `DisplayName` but its not working for me.

I have upgraded the SDK for SP2013 but still i am unable to find this property. Can you please let me know if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

Include the `DisplayName` in your `.Include`:

```
clientContext.Load(webFeatures, fcol => fcol.Include( f => f.DefinitionId, f=> f.DisplayName));
```